# Reference standard HTML elements in schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a custom xml schema that have an HTML type. I want to reference a couple of "standard" html elements that can be used inside this html type(a, p, ul, etc.).
I have found the following schema that have those elements.

http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd

I added the following line to import the schema

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd" />
```

and I'm trying to use the elements inside like the following

```
<xs:complexType name="Html">
  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="ul"></xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

It's not working, what I'm I missing? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML elements defined in the imported schema are in the xhtml namespace: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. Therefore you should add also a `namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute to your `<xs:import>` element. In order to refer to the elements and types defined in the imported schema you need to have a namespace definition with some prefix for the xhtml namespace. That is: you need to have for example `xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` definition in your `<xs:schema>` element and then use this prefix (here `xh`) when you refer to types, elements, etc. defined in the XHTML schema.

So your sample code becomes:

```
<xs:schema 
    ... 
    xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    ...
    >

<xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd"
           namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />

    <xs:complexType name="Html">
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="xh:ul"></xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```